# How does hyperledger composer participant maps to hyperledger fabric entities?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In hyperledger composer documentation "In order for a new participant to join a business network, a new instance of that participant must be created in the business network".
I understand business network weakly maps to chaincode in fabric. How exactly a participant instance is represented in fabric ? Is it stored in ledger state data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the data for a participant is stored in world-state. There is a also a mapping table that allows the Fabric certificate to be mapped to the participant id.